# OpenCV Hough Lines Not Showing

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to get the lines from the following image:
[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8g0o.jpg)

My code uses the following function:

```py
import cv2
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image, .1, np.pi/360, 10,
                        minLineLength, maxLineGap)
```

Where `minLineLength` = 20, and `maxLineGap` = 10. I am obtaining the following:
[after hough lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRutL.jpg)

Why are the horizontal lines not showing up in this case, despite being clearly visible to the naked eye?

Comment: I am not sure but in the original image I can not see any lines "clearly visible"... do you mean the image without the threshold? I believe you uploaded the wrong image, please edit so we can help better. It could be because they dont have the `minLineLength` you specified, maybe with lower value will detect them.

Comment: It's the correct image. Shouldn't the top edge of the rectangle register as a horizontal hough line?

Comment: The resolution for rho in pixel is too small. Try 1 instead of 0.1. With small values the risk is that you do not accumulate enough pixels in any bin of the accumulator to reach the threshold you set at 10. For an image like yours, it doesn't make sense to use this 0.1.

Comment: @Eskapp comment is important. The rho parameter is measured in pixels, so giving it fractions of pixels (something unrealistic) could produce unexpected results. Posted an answer based on my suggestion and included also the rho consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the resolution that you use for rho.

A resolution of 0.1 is extremely small. Indeed for an image of size `(N, N)` pixels, the number of possible values for rho is `N * N * sqrt(2) / rho_resolution` (sometimes the double of this depending of how the angle is defined).

The number of possible values is materialized as bins in the Hough accumulator. The larger this number, the less the different pixels of the image will accumulate is the same bins. With a very small value for the resolution of rho, you will end up with a sparse accumulator, with a few low values here and there.

Bring this value up to 1 or 2 pixels of resolution and you should see more significant lines appear.

Answer (score 0):

If `HoughLinesP()` is *not* detecting some line, even though it is clearly visible, it is because that line surely does not meet some of your criteria. Most probably your `minLineLength` or `maxLineGap`. If you reduce those criteria you will start detecting more lines.

Also, as some comments indicate, your rho parameter may be too small (0.1). As that parameter is measured in *pixels*, giving it a non-integer value may produce unexpected results, try giving it a value of 1.

If you want you can take a look at this [example](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html) from the docs where they explain and show how to use both `HoughLines()` and `HoughLinesP()`.